# Deserialize JSON array to Swift objects using SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, json, swift, swifty-json

Given this JSON:

```
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Bananas",
    "rating" : 4
  },
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "Tacos",
    "rating" : 3
  },
  {
    "id" : 3,
    "name" : "Apple",
    "rating" : 5
  }
```

How can you create an array of Swift objects using SwiftyJSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var jsonObjectArray = JSON(swiftStr).array!
var swiftArray = []
for jsonObject in jsonObjectArray {
   var swiftObject = SwiftObject()
   swiftObject.propetyName = jsonObject["propertyName"].string!
   swiftArry.append(swiftObject)
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I would create a struct from each dictionary and store the structs in an array.

The struct:

```
struct MyObject {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let rating: Int
}
```

An array to store the struct instances:

```
var objects: [MyObject] = []
```

Let SwiftyJSON parse your JSON data:

```
let jsonArray = JSON(data: myData)
```

Create the structs and append them to the new array:

```
for (index, dict) in jsonArray {
    let thisObject = MyObject(id: dict["id"].intValue, name: dict["name"].stringValue, rating: dict["rating"].intValue)
    objects.append(thisObject)
}
```

Now you have an array of Swift structs (it could be classes, of course) reflecting the JSON content:

```
for object in objects {
    print("ID: \(object.id), NAME: \(object.name), RATING: \(object.rating)")
}
```

Prints:

> ID: 1, NAME: Bananas, RATING: 4
>   ID: 2, NAME: Tacos, RATING: 3
>   ID: 3, NAME: Apple, RATING: 5

Note that I'm using the non-optional getters of SwiftyJSON, `.intValue` and `.stringValue`, because I assume these fields will always be there. If you think there could be nils, you should make the struct properties Optional and use the optional getters `.int` and `.string`.

Answer (score 1):

```
let jsonString = "[{\"id\" : 1,\"name\" : \"Bananas\",\"rating\" : 4},{\"id\" : 2,\"name\" : \"Tacos\",\"rating\" : 3},{\"id\" : 3,\"name\" : \"Apple\",\"rating\" : 5}]"
if let dataFromString = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false) {
    let json = JSON(data: dataFromString)

    let element1 = json[0]
    let element2 = json[1]
    let element3 = json[2]

}
```